# Some images or doc files are successfully uploaded but video is not uploaded using PHP

Tags: php, forms

Some images or doc files are successfully uploaded but video is not uploaded using PHP. Can any one tell me what is the problem in my code.

```
<?php
   include('conn.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
 </head>
   <body>
     <form name="form1" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-   data"/>
      upload file<input type="file" name="f"><br/>
       name:<input type="text" name="t"><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="submit">
    <?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
      {
        $filename=$_POST['t'];
        $fnm=$_FILES["f"]["name"];
        $dst="./data/".$fnm;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["f"]["tmp_name"],$dst);
        $query="insert into up(filename,name,path) values('$filename','$fnm','$dst')";
       $query1=mysqli_query($con,$query);
       if($query1==true)
          {
            echo "insert data";
          }
      else
          {
            echo "not inserted";
          }
 }

?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on for your php code? Are you getting any PHP errors ?

Comment: Sorry, but questions along the line "why isn't this code working" are clearly off-topic here. You are expected to debug yourself and to point to specific issues you see.

Comment: Apart from that: your code is _wide_ open to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Maybe the data being uploaded exceeds a set maximum request limit?

Comment: i din't getting any error but some files like .txt,doc are uploaded successfully but some images or videos are not uploaded

Comment: Maybe a server max file size or max post size configuration